# Ways to only use word-based challenges in recapcha plugin?

Tags: recaptcha

I am using a recapcha plugin for my site, is there a way to get only word-base challenges and not any number challenges ?

Comment: You already have problems typing this question. Are you sure you want to be using words in your captcha?

Comment: Yes, really need to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for some time i've found that this is not possible , because captcha uses a third party and the challenges sent are at random.